# Is there a simple or automated way to know if my Google Workspace add-on would trigger a security assessment?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I am planning to create and publish a Google Sheets add-on to the public in the Google Workspace marketplace. To my knowledge, for certain types of add-ons that use restricted scopes, Google requires a third party security assessment/audit to be done on the add-ons. It costs between $15k-$75k and several weeks to process the audit. I don't plan to pay this hefty fee especially if the add-on is free.

The documentation and the circumstances of whether an add-on will require a security assessment are not clear enough to me. For example, getting a list of Gmail drafts when the add-on user clicks on a button to get a list of them.

Before I spend time creating a finished add-on, is there a way to submit a quick and dirty add-on, with the API calls I plan to use, to Google just to see if the add-on is going to require a security audit? My goal is not to implement a feature if it's going to require a security audit.

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*If your add-on uses any of the following scopes, it will require a security assessment:*

> **Gmail API**
>
> - https://mail.google.com/ (includes any usage of IMAP, SMTP, and POP3 protocols)
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.metadata
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.insert
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.basic
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.settings.sharing
>
> **Google Fit API**
>
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.activity.read
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_glucose.read
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.blood_pressure.read
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body.read
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.body_temperature.read
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.heart_rate.read
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.location.read
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.nutrition.read
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.oxygen_saturation.read
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.reproductive_health.read
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fitness.sleep.read
>
> **Drive API**
>
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.activity.readonly
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.scripts
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata
> - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly

Further information about the OAuth API verification process can be found [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914), including the above list of restricted scopes which require verification.

Comment: Yeah I am aware of all this. I was specifically asking if there's a 'simple' or 'automated' way to just determine in a few seconds/minutes if the add-on will require a security assessment without someone at Google manually and formally going through the process of determining this. I don't want the add-on to actually be published.

I am seeing a bunch of free 'simple' add-ons/Chrome extensions (no paid features) from what seem to be developed by solo developers and I hardly believe they paid at least $15k to be published and I am pretty sure they used restricted scope APIs.

Comment: If you're not publishing your add-on (i.e keeping it internal for you domain) then you don't need to go through verifiction.

Comment: If publishing, then the add-on will require a security assessment if and only if you use any of the above scopes. That's all you have to worry about - the security assessment will take place 100% of the time if you use one of the scopes, and will not take place 100% of the time if you don't use any of them. As long as you know your scopes then that's all you need to know if a security assessment will be required.

Comment: As for the price of an assessment - you won't know this until you go through the publication process.